Percentage From Linearized Exponential Decay
I have approximated a function to resemble some data that I took:
$$
f(x) = Ae^{B(x - C)} + D
$$
with values of:

A = 248
B = -0.0025
C = 20
D = 105

I have attempted to linearize it and got the following:
$$
ln(y - D) = B(x - C) + ln(A)
$$
when attempting to convert this to a percentage I got:
$$
percent = (\frac{ln(y - D) - ln(A) + BC}{B}) * 100 = (\frac{ln(\frac{y - D}{A})}{B} + C)*100 
$$
my output then ranged from 3900% to -220,800%.
Which part of this process went wrong, or could it perhaps be an issue with the data/approximation.

Turns out I was complicating it more than I needed to. The linearization was correct, in that when treating $ln(y - D)$ as a new "y" (we'll call it $y'$), it gave a linear correlation, but when converting that to a percent all I needed to do was:
$$
percent = \frac{y' - y'_{start}}{y'_{end} - y'_{start}} * 100
$$
